# switch installation location of gcc

Tags: gcc

I've got two installations of gcc on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.  Ordinarily selecting between them wouldn't be a problem, but the installation location of one is perplexing.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'sc-gcc-4.9.3' for regex 'gcc-4.9'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.9-base' for regex 'gcc-4.9'
gcc-4.9-base is already the newest version.
sc-gcc-4.9.3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ /usr/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         428 May  7  2006 c89-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         454 Apr 11  2011 c99-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           7 Apr  7  2014 gcc -> gcc-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root      775888 May  7  2016 gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 Apr  7  2014 gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       26968 May  7  2016 gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 Apr  7  2014 gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       26968 May  7  2016 gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          14 Apr  7  2014 gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-4.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       26968 May  7  2016 gcc-ranlib-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           7 Apr  7  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           7 May  7  2016 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8 -> gcc-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 Apr  7  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 May  7  2016 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-4.8 -> gcc-ar-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 Apr  7  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          10 May  7  2016 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-4.8 -> gcc-nm-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          14 Apr  7  2014 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-4.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          14 May  7  2016 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-4.8 -> gcc-ranlib-4.8

$ apt-cache policy sc-gcc-4.9.3
sc-gcc-4.9.3:
  Installed: 1-20160726
  Candidate: 1-20160726
  Version table:
 *** 1-20160726 0
        500 http://usa-mirror.internal.net/mirrors/stable/3rdparty/trusty/ ./ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So apt-get knows that gcc-4.9 is installed, but I'm unsure why it ended up in /usr/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin instead of /usr/bin.

Can anyone provide some light on this?
What's the best practice of how to update the links?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result of `apt-cache policy sc-gcc-4.9.3` so we can see its origin

Comment: The sc-gcc-4.9.3 is a third party package, so they decide where they want to install gcc.  Does it provide anything the normal 4.9.3 gcc install doesn't?

Comment: Let's assume the answer is yes.  Is the right way to use update-alternatives or something to select between them?